# How put autoplay relation video for embed youtube?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, embed

I need put autoplay for embed youtube. I means, autoplay next video. I thinking about it but i can't find the way. Someone can help me? Thanks

Sorry for my bad english

[image: autoplay option]

Comment: Rel:1 not working

Comment: Rel is similar really, i need rel with autoplay next video